# Are individual church members the rooms in John 14:2?

Tags: greek, john

In John 14:23, Jesus says:

> Anyone who loves me will obey my teaching. My Father will love them, and we will come to them and make **our home** with them.`

The Greek word for home (μονὴν) is the same root word used by Jesus in John 14:2.

> My Father's house has many rooms (μοναὶ)

Is it possible to read John 14:2 in the light of John 14:23, so that individual believers are the rooms in which God comes to dwell? The Father's house is the church. Individual members of that church are the rooms, in which God dwells by his Spirit?

Comment: It is much more likely that they are gatherings of individual churches, people known to one another in this life, who have sojourned together and shared Christ together. Rather than lonely individuals in separated accommodation. This is just a _likely_ interpretation so not an answer, just a comment. Up-voted +1. Good question.

Answer (score 1):

Not so fast.  There are two different metaphors in view in these two passages, although that does not show up so well in English and the modern idiom.

**Idiom/metaphor #1 - John 14:1-3 - Marriage Preparations**

The first three verses of John 14 use the marriage idiom to describe what Jesus is about to do.  In a normal eastern marriage, following courtship and the marriage contract, the bridegroom would "go away" to prepare the house for the bride to be.  Following the completion of the house, the bridegroom would return to collect the bride, celebrate the marriage and take her to the new home recently completed.

Jesus says almost exactly the same thing - He is going away, to prepare homes for the saved, He will return to collect the saints, and take them to their new home to live with Him.

**Idiom/metaphor #2 - John 14:23 - Guest arrival**

V23 alludes to a different custom of arriving at someone's home and being welcomed by the homeowner.  Jesus wants to dwell with/in us by His Holy Spirit (V16, 26, etc).

Thus, the two scenarios refer to different times in the Christian's life:

- Idiom/metaphor #1 refers to what happens after glorification when all the saints go physically to live with God and Jesus as described in Rev 21
- Idiom/metaphor #2 refers to what happens when Jesus "goes away", ie, during our Christian life on earth as described in greater detail in John 15:1-10.

Comment: Is Scenario #2 refer to Idiom #1 and Scenario #1 as Idiom #2?

Comment: @VincentWong - yes - I will clarify this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please can you let me know whether there is any evidence that weddings were conducted in that way. I've heard that explanation before but I don't know if it's speculation or whether there is any authority for that view.

Comment: @AndrewCrisp - One can see the consummation of the "spiritual marriage" between the Lamb and His bride, the church in Rev 19:6-10 which is anticipated by Matt 25:1-10.